# I am not able to change the python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8, python-3.10

Previously, I used to use python3.8. But recently, I have downloaded python 3.10. And also changed the path variable to the newer python version. But still, when I run the python version command in cmd, I am seeing the older version.

The path of python 3.10, I gave in the path field of Environment variables is: C:\Users\vssnr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

But in cmd, when I ran the following the results are looking like this :

**Command 1: pip --version**

> pip 22.0.4 from
> C:\Users\vssnr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip
> (python 3.10)

**Command 2: python -m pip install --upgrade pip**

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages)
> Requirement already satisfied: pip in
> c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages
> (22.0.4) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\vssnr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages)

**Command 3: python --version**

> Python 3.8.10

All these commands are given at the same location. Please inform me how I can able to shift to Python 3.10. Also to uninstall the python3.8, I am not able to find it in uninstalling the apps, but I can find the 3.10 one. Please tell me why can not I find the python 3.8 in this location  >> Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

Comment: Seems like your PATH is messed up, containing Python 3.8.10 but the Scripts for Python 3.10. Enter your paths here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176423/10513287

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, there can be a PATH problem. You can add the Python to Windows Path like this https://geek-university.com/add-python-to-the-windows-path/ and you can check again Python versions with commands on cmd: `python -v` or `python3 -v`